# Why are you running here running there?

Tags: grammar

He ran to the living room then ran to kitchen.
He kept ran and ran.

"**Why are you running here running there?**" I asked him.

Does it sound grammatically correct to an native speaker?

Comment: Try this idiom: why are you keep running **here and there**?

Comment: @user178049 Why **do** you keep running...

Comment: He kept running and running : [keep verb (CONTINUE DOING)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/keep?q=keep+).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If "he" just kept running erratically throughout the house, I'd say:

  > Why do you keep on running?
- If by *here* and *there* you just mean the living room and the kitchen, then you can say:

  > Why are you running back and forth?

*Back and forth* in the [Wiktionary:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/back_and_forth)

> From one place to another and back again.